# Substring everything after match

Tags: swift

So I'm trying to substring everything after a match, but I'm only getting a single char for some reason.

```
let url = "http://localhost:3000/something/?page=2&per_page=20" 

if let pageNumber = url.range(of: "per_page=", options: .backwards) {
    // this prints "0" ? was kinda hoping for "20"
    print(url.substring(from: pageNumber.upperBound))
}
```

Edit: Ok I changed the string to per_page without the "=" and now it works. No idea why.

```
.. url.range(of: "per_page", ..
```

Comment: Your code prints 20 for me once I added the missing curly brace at the end of `if let`.

Comment: Okay missed that bracket in this post but I had it in my code and it's still printing 0 for me. Now I'am even more confused.

Comment: That's odd - all I did was pasting your code into a playground.

Comment: You are encouraged to update to Swift 4  And the question is not related to `NSString` (see tag) at all.

Comment: Please give an example of how to do it in Swift 4 and I will accept the answer :D. Hence the question.

Comment: Per the standard, query parameters are unordered. So `...?page=2&per_page=20` should be equivalent to `?&per_page=20&page=2`. The problem with this manual substringing approach is that it's brittle against this reordering. It's better to use the standard library to help you.

Comment: That's very true, i'm not very fond of subtringing string header values. I will need to think of something more robust. Good comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 4 this code is supposed to work

```
let url = "http://localhost:3000/something/?page=2&per_page=20"

if let pageNumber = url.range(of: "per_page=", options: .backwards) {
    print(url[pageNumber.upperBound...])
}
```

---

However if the string represents an URL I recommend the `URLComponents` API.

- Create an `URLComponents` instance from the URL
- Get the `QueryItems`
- Filter the desired `key`
- Get the `value`

  ```
  let url = "http://localhost:3000/something/?page=2&per_page=20"
  if let urlComponents = URLComponents(string: url),
      let queryItems = urlComponents.queryItems,
      let perPage = queryItems.first(where: {$0.name == "per_page"}) {
          print(perPage.value!)
  }
  ```

Comment: Sweet! It is an actual string sadly because im looking at a [AnyHashable:Any] dictionary.

Comment: @vadian Do you know if multiple query items can have the same name? From what I can tell, they can't, but I can't find a source on it. If they are unique, then I would recommend an extension like this: https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/5f70ff3ba6fc4698ab15f2df920fa907.

Comment: Looks very neat! I will try it out, thank you for your addition!